# Signature for accessing Webservice client after wsimport

Tags: webservice-client

Using the WeatherService?wsdl ( deployed into Axis2) and sucessfully creating set of client files (using wsimport)

the following package / files are generated

```
\CLIENT\src\sample\pojo\data\xsd
ObjectFactory.java
package-info.java
Weather.java

\CLIENT\src\sample\pojo\service

GetWeatherResponse.java
ObjectFactory.java
package-info.java
SetWeather.java
WeatherService.java
WeatherServicePortType.java
```

How to proceed and which files to use from the list to process the WSDL and execute ???

Please provide client code with starting point ( public static main(String args[])

with regards
karthik